# Adopt Spring Roo and JBoss Forge

Tags: spring, maven, jboss, spring-roo

`Roo` is tied to `Spring framework` and `Maven` is inherent, while `Forge` is closely related to `Java EE/JBoss-AS` and Maven becomes optional.

- Can we use either of them to scaffold something independent of `programming models`, namely `Spring framework` or `Java EE/CDI` herewith?
- Any pointers about `Forge and Maven integration`? Quick google leads to no useful links yet.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2 years I use Telosys Tools (instead of ROO) for Java applications scaffolding
because this code generator is simple and independent of any kind of environment
(it's possible to generate anything : Java, HTML, Python, etc...)

Some predefined templates are available on GitHub, if they don't match your needs you can create your own templates for your specific targets

cf tutorials : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Telosys ( http://www.telosys.org/ ) is a good tool to bootstrap a project. The scaffolding is possible from a database or from a lightweight text model.

The code generation is based on Velocity templates so you can customize existing templates or create your own templates.

Everything is free and Open Source (generator and templates).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that ties Forge to JBoss AS or really Java EE for that matter. At it's core Forge is a shell for generating resources. The available plugins tend to be Java EE focused, but they don't have to be.

Have a look at the [Forge website](http://forge.jboss.org/). There is plenty of information on it there. Also JBoss Tools has nice integration with it if you use eclipse too.